# Check the field type of all the attributes of an entry

Tags: plugin-development, relations, plugin-elementapi, entries-field, query

Here's the whole picture:

I'm trying to make an API endpoint which should output everything from an entry:

First I did this:

```
    public function transform(Entry $entry)
    {

        return $entry->getAttributes();
    }
```

That outputs every field on the entry. But, in the fields containing related items like `categories` or `header_images`, In the response I got,looks like the query without being executed:

```
{
    ...
    "from": null,
    "groupBy": null,
    "join": [
        [
            "INNER JOIN",
            "{{%relations}} relations", [
                "and",
                "[[relations.targetId]] = [[elements.id]]",
                {
                    "relations.sourceId": "35",
                    "relations.fieldId": "15"
                },
                [
                    "or",
                    {
                        "relations.sourceSiteId": null
                    },
                    {
                        "relations.sourceSiteId": "4"
                    }
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
    ...
}
```

I found out that doing `->all()`, I get the correct response.

```
    public function transform(Entry $entry)
    {
        $attributes = $entry->getAttributes();

        $attributes['categories'] = $entry->categories->all();

        $attributes['header_image'] = $entry->header_image->all();

        foreach ($attributes['header_image'] as $key => $image) {
            $attributes['header_image'][$key] = $image->toArray();
            $attributes['header_image'][$key]['folder'] = $image->getVolume();
        }

        return $attributes;
    }
```

But of course that limits me cause I have to know the field handle (header_image).

*First: is there a smart/better way to get the related?*

The idea I got to solve this is: Loop through all the fields, and if the type is `Asset` or `Category`, do the `->all()`. But I cannot get the type of the field. I'm trying stuff like:

```
        $fields = $entry->getFieldLayout()->getFields();

        foreach ($fields as $field) {
            $field->getContentColumnType(); //Or something
        }
```

But well, doesn't really work.